# after Adding header file to dependency, makefile didn't work for main.cpp

Tags: c++, makefile

```
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11

SRC_DIR    := src
HEADER_DIR := include
BIN_DIR    := bin
OBJ_DIR     := $(BIN_DIR)/obj

EXECUTABLE := $(BIN_DIR)/main

OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,main.o admin.o number.o SHA256.o signatures.o user.o)


all: $(EXECUTABLE)

directories:
    mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o $@ $(CPPFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) 
    
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(HEADER_DIR)/%.h
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(HEADER_DIR)


clean: 
    del $(OBJ_DIR)\*.o $(EXECUTABLE)
    CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11
```

Above is my makefile. It doesn't update after main.cpp gets changed while it works for main.cpp only when I remove the header file from the dependency.
i.e. change this line `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(HEADER_DIR)/%.h`
to
`$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp` 
Why is that happening?

Comment: What are the values of the variables? What is the error?

Comment: @user17732522 Just updated it, plz check. There's no error message. It is the problem that the makefile doesn't update after main.cpp gets changed

Comment: "doesn't work" is insufficient for a problem description. That phrase covers everything from "quits without doing anything" to "spits out a billion error messages" to "my computer literally melted so I'm posting this from my phone while I wait for the cleaning service".

Comment: What would you expect to see? What do you see instead? What make target are you specifying? Are the other targets relevant to this question? Are you properly using tabs to indent the Makefile? What exactly do you do when you "remove the header file from the dependency"? Have you tried to isolate the problem to a [mcve]?

Comment: It works fine in my linux machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(HEADER_DIR)/%.h
```

tells make how to build an object file **if and only if** it can find an appropriately named `.cpp` file *and* an appropriately named `.h` file.  If either of those files cannot be found, and make can't find a rule to build them, then this rule doesn't match and make will continue looking for some other rule to build the object file.

If no other rule is found, make will tell you that there is no rule to build the object file.

If you're getting this error for `main.cpp`, then it means that there is no corresponding `main.h` file.

You either need to create a `main.h` file, or change this pattern rule to not put the header as a prerequisite (you add the headers of other files as prerequisites directly), or create a new pattern rule that doesn't require the header.